# I can't arrange messages in new line in <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

My `<div>` contains a message from a message array, but I can't show it in a new line in UI. It all comes in the same line.

[image]

My code is:

```
<div className="md:container xl:mx-auto  space-y-1  border-zinc-800 rounded border-2 w-30 h-60 bg-blue-300">
      <h2 className="font-serif text-xl">{_message.map((Message) => Message)}</h2>
</div>
```

I want my all new messages come in new line

Comment: CSS: `white-space: pre`

Answer (score 2):

Add the `whitespace-pre` class to the `<h2>`:

```html
<div className="md:container xl:mx-auto  space-y-1  border-zinc-800 rounded border-2 w-30 h-60 bg-blue-300">
  <h2 className="font-serif text-xl whitespace-pre">{_message.map((Message) => Message)}</h2>
</div>
```

This way, if the text contains line-feeds, they are preserved visually.

See: [Whitespace - Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

You have `_messages` array and you are placing everything inside the `h2`. that is why it looks like this

### item1 item2 item3

Instead for each array item, you should have `h2` or better way, you should have a separate component.

```
 // this is simplified. you might need to pass more props. maybe username etc
 {_message.map((message) => <MessageComponent content={message} />)}
```

`MessageComponent` should be like this:

```
const MessageComponent=({content})=>{
   return (
       <div className="flex flex-col" >{content}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly rendering the text per item in the _message array. Text is treated as an inline element. You could wrap the message text in block elements like `div` or `p` to show each item in a new line. Something like this:

```
<div className="md:container xl:mx-auto  space-y-1  border-zinc-800 rounded border-2 w-30 h-60 bg-blue-300">
    <h2 className="font-serif text-xl">{_message.map((Message) => <div>Message</div>)}</h2>
</div>
```

As @Yilmaz suggests, you could also render a custom component and style it based on your requirements.